# Outer Lebesgue measure - countable sub-additivity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Denote
$$
m^*(\Omega) := \inf \left \{ \sum_{k=0}^\infty vol(B_k) : (B_k)_{k=0}^\infty \text{ covers } \Omega \right \}
$$ where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and the $B_k$ are open boxes of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i)$.

I want to show that
$$
 m^*\left (\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_j \right ) \leq \sum_{j=0}^\infty m^*(A_j)
$$ where $(A_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is a countable familiy of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

My proof: If one of the $m^*(A_j) = \infty$ we are done. So assume that all of the $m^*(A_j) < \infty$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. By the definition of $m^*$ we can find an open cover $(B_k^{(j)})_{k=0}^\infty$ of $A_j$ s.t.
$$
 m^*(A_j) \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty vol(B_k^{(j)}) < m^*(A_j) + \frac \epsilon {2^j}
$$ Then $\cup_{(j,k) \in \mathbb N^2} B_k^{(j)}$ is an open cover of $\cup_{j=0}^\infty A_j$. Thus
$$
 m^* \left (\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_j \right ) \leq \sum_{(j,k) \in \mathbb N^2} vol(B_k^{(j)}) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty vol(B_k^{(j)})
$$

My question: Is the last step legal ? I thought of Fubini's theorem but I am not sure.

Comment: All the terms in the series are positive...so standard theorems about absolute convergence allow you to do this. Fubini's Theorem is an overkill.

Comment: Do you have some references ? Is the equality true or is it in fact $\leq$ ?

Comment: Look at Rudin's 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis' for example.